# custom join query to get result from 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 4 tables in mysql database like following:

**Table : videos**

```
id    name
1     name1
2     name2
```

**Table : channels**

```
id    name       media_image_id
1     channel1   5
```

**Table : channel_has_videos**

```
channel_id    video_id
1             2
```

**Table : media_image**

```
id    filename
5     filefive.jpg
```

Here I would like to get `videos.name` + `media_image.filename` of channel where video belongs to channel.

So here desire output will be:

```
id    name    filename
2     name2   filefive.jpg
```

I tried but did not get exact what i want.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `join` all the tables. The result will return if data is found across all the tables

```
select
v.id.
v.name,
mi.filename
from channel_has_videos chv 
join channels c on c.id = chv.channel_id
join videos v on v.id = chv.video_id
join media_image mi on mi.id = c.media_image_id
```